# Automation Tools For Mobile Apps

Tags: mobile

Is there any open source automation testing tool which can be used for Android, iOS, Windows, Blackberry for native and hybrid applications without rooting?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use Appium for Android, iOS and Windows mobile automation.*

*It is an open source cross platform tool which you can easily use.*
*You can check it* [here.](http://appium.io/)

*You can download **appium for desktop** from* [here.](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.5.0)

*Appium for desktop is used as **inspector** for locating the elements for both android and iOS applications.*